# How does the audio output gets changed when headphones are plugged in an Android? How to set the headphone port also

Tags: android, xiaomi, miui

I am trying to change the audio output port of my Xiaomi device from type c to 3.5mm audio jack.

I tried to find codes in build prop and other audio files. Exchanged audio server file with a rom which had 3.5mm audio port.